# Practical applications of SLLN where WLLN does not suffice?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

Are there any practical applications of the Strong Law of Large Numbers for which the Weak Law of Large Numbers would not suffice?

When, in practice, is the result 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mathbf{P}\biggl[\Bigl|\frac{1}{n}\bigl(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n\bigr)-\mu\Bigr|\ge\varepsilon \biggr] = 0$$
not enough?

When is 
$$\mathbf{P}\biggr[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\bigl(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n\bigr) = \mu\biggl]=1$$
needed?

Thank you!